# Run method during CSV upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, unidecoder

I have a simple CSV uploader below that is going row by row and creating a new record (event). I also have the unidecoder gem in use and would like to call the `to_ascii` method on a field (the description field) that is in every record being created by the CSV uploader. It sounds like it should be simple, but I'm not familiar with iterating through a CSV file.

The uploader:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "windows-1252:utf-8") do |row|
    Event.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

Correct way of implementing this:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "windows-1252:utf-8") do |row|
    description = row[2]
    row[2] = description.to_ascii

    Event.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "windows-1252:utf-8") do |row|
    unless row[1].blank?
      description = row[1] # Change 1 for the correct column
      row[1] = description.to_ascii
    end

    Event.create! row
end
```

If the description is not blank (empty), extract and update the value (description) and then save it.

`row` is an Array of you comma separated values, for example a CSV file like `name, description, address`, the `row[1]` have the value of the description.

Comment: Odd, it says that `to_ascii` isn't a method. I've never actually used it in the model, but instead in the controller. I'm fairly new to Rails, so don't know how to proceed. Any thoughts?

Comment: "NoMethodError at /events/import
undefined method `to_ascii' for nil:NilClass"

Here is the Github for unidecoder gem: https://github.com/norman/unidecoder

Comment: so row is an array of a single "event" in this case? I have several fields and it will still iterate through each field?

Also, is changing row[1] in description = row[1] necessary? I have headers, and understood that it maps the header to the correct database field

Comment: Yes, a row is an Event. YOu don't need to iterate through each field. Changing rou is necessary because you need to call the `to_ascii` method on description. You can use a simple way of debugging to see what's happening in you `self.import` method by printing the row: `puts row` and `puts row.to_hash`.

Comment: I got it all working now. I updated the question with the correct solution. Thanks for guiding me there cortex!